# Can I search music.youtube.com using youtube-dl / yt-dlp?

Tags: youtube-dl, yt-dlp

I am writing a discord music bot. If I do

```
$ yt-dlp ytsearch:"some query"
```

yt-dlp searches youtube.com. It'd be better if I can directly search music.youtube.com than youtube.com (since I can get the songs directly). Can I search music.youtube.com using yt-dlp or filter music videos from youtube?

If it is not possible with just the shell, can I do it with python? If yes, how.

Comment: Turns out these kinds of bots are against YouTube's TOS (even non copyrighted music). I have dropped this project and this question / answer stays for educational purposes only.

Answer (score 0):

There is this unofficial library to interact with music.youtube.com called [ytmusicapi](https://ytmusicapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Using this library, we can get the link of the video needed and then use it with yt-dlp.

The code goes something like this

```py
import ytmusicapi
yt = ytmusicapi.YTMusic()
query = "unity fat rat"
videoId = yt.search(query)[0]["videoId"]
```

This `videoId` can then be used with yt-dlp.